# Do the individual claws of a bear have names?

Tags: zoology, anatomy, mammals

The question seems pretty self-explanatory (if perhaps a little odd). Anatomical names or colloquial names are both appreciated, especially the latter if they exist.

Answer (score -3):

I would be surprised if they do!

Bears have 5 clearly visible toes per paw. You could just name the claws based on the fingers it is on (thumb, index, middle, ring, pinky).